# pycharm can't find python

Tags: software-installation, python3

When I try to run pycharm it shows this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot start PyCharm
No JDK found. Please validate either PYCHARM_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

I typed python into my terminal and it shows that I have python 3.4 installed, but pycharm cant access it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post the exact error messages.

Comment: which error messages?

Comment: What pycharm tells you that makes you think you need the "python jdk"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with Python. JDK stands for Java Development Kit, which PyCharm need in order to run.

Try this link to install the Open JDK:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788345/how-to-install-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux

Comment: Thanks that worked! The Ubuntu community is really amazing!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today and the selected answer above did not help. This is what I did to resolve mine.

I installed pycharm via getdeb repository so my installation folder is located at: `/usr/share/pycharm`. In order to fix this issue steps are:

1. `sudo gedit` or `sudo xed` `/usr/share/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh`
2. find Line: JDK=`update-alternatives --list java | grep java-8 | sed 's,jre/bin/java,,' and replace it with JDK = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/' or JDK = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/' if you're using openjdk.
3. Save and exit, then try running pycharms again. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

`No JDK found` means that it can't find Java on your machine. So check if Java is installed--if not, install it.